# May we still say Elohim and other names of God in everyday speech?

Tags: halacha, theology, shemos-sacred-names, speech-talking

My experience (at least in the Orthodox Ashkenazic community) is that it is common knowledge that we may not say Elohim in everyday speech. On the other hand, it seems like in many cases in Tanach or Talmud the name Elohim or similar is used in conversational terms or at least not directly in a blessing.

Is this true Halacha as many Ashkenazim appear to think it is, is it more of a minhag that has the force of Halacha, or is it not true?

And if it is forbidden as many seem to think it is, then why *can't* we say God's name? Also is there one name that is forbidden while other terms are not? For example many places and names include "el" in them and that seems to be fine.

Also, in practice, if you speak Hebrew and want to teach a child about God, do you actually use a fake word like "Elokim" to discuss it?

Comment: Who says we aren't?

Comment: Well aside from the other answer quoting Kitzur Shulchan Aruch, common knowledge. (But I don't understand why, and "fear of God" doesn't really explain it.) Unless you have a source or example to the contrary?

Comment: Can you  edit into your question the reason why you perceive you are not allowed to pronounce the name, and the rest of the question and information that you provided in the comment below that the moderator suggested you include.  These will strengthen you question by making it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Kitzur Shulchan Aruch ([6:3](http://www.yonanewman.org/kizzur/kizzur6.html)) writes:

> אסור להוציא שם שמים לבטלה  וכל המוציא שם שמים לבטלה  עובר על מצות עשה
> דכתיב  את ה' אלהיך תירא  וכתיב  אם לא תשמור וגו  ליראה את השם הנכבד
> והנורא וזהו מכלל היראה  שלא להזכיר שמו הגדול  כי אם בדרך שבח וברכה
> במה שהוא מחויב או בדרך לימוד  ויירא  ויזדעזעו אבריו  בשעה שהוא מזכיר
> את השם  יתברך שמו אבל לא להוציאו  חס ושלום לבטלה  ולא שם המיוחד בלבד
> אלא כל השמות המיוחדים לשמו  יתברך  ולא לבד בלשון הקודש  אסור  אלא
> אפילו בכל לשון אסור
>
> It is forbidden to say G-d's name (lit. ''the Heavenly Name'') in
> vain,  and everyone who says G-d's name in vain  transgresses a
> positive commandment,  as it is written:   ''The Lord your G-d you
> shall fear;''  and it is (again) written:   ''If you will not observe
> ...  to fear the glorious and awesome Name.''  This (we learn) from
> the concept of fear,  that one should not mention His great Name
> except by way of praise or blessing  whenever required,  or when
> (Torah) learning.  One should be fearful  and one's entire body
> tremble  when mentioning the name,  blessed be His name,  but one
> should not say it  G-d forbid, in vain;  And (this applies) not only
> to the special Name  but to all the names specially referring to
> Him,  may He be blessed.  It is not just in (Hebrew) the Holy Tongue,
> that (mentioning the Name) is forbidden,  but even in any language it
> is forbidden.

Comment: There's a big gap between "in vain" and "only while learning Torah or praying".

Comment: @DoubleAA Seems like Kitzur Shulchan Aruch considers any other use as in vain.

Comment: It is not universally accepted or practiced to avoid saying the English equivalent of Hashem's name (see *Shach* YD 179:11).

Comment: My question is *why* can't we say God's name, not *is* it forbidden. Meaning, if it is forbidden, why does it seem like in many cases in Tanach or Talmud the name Elokim or similar is used in conversational terms or at least not directly in a blessing? If you speak Hebrew and want to teach a child about God, do you actually use a fake word to discuss it? Also what does it refer to by "the Heavenly Name"? Is there one name that is forbidden while other terms are not? For example many places and names include "el" in them and that seems to be fine.

Comment: @AL Why not [include](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/20465/edit) all of that in the question? Remember, the clearer and more explicit you make your question, the better the responses will be.

Comment: @AL The Kitzur Shulchan Aruch explains why; it is considered a lack of fear of Hashem to use his Name conversationally.

Comment: @Michoel ok then let me rephrase my question. Why was it okay in the past but not today?

Comment: @AL That's a different question; not why it is forbidden but what changed. I'm not sure if site protocol is to edit this question or to ask a new one?

Comment: Site protocol is always developing over on meta http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1229/759

Comment: @DoubleAA Does current protocol consider one up-vote as valuable [Or do we m'dayek that miyut rabim shnayim :-)]?

Comment: i would like to see another source for this prohibition. Because as others pointed out, the Kitzur SA you quote says other things are prohibited that the majority of rishonim say are permitted, such was writing or saying the name God in other languages.