# What if somebody says the Shem Hameforash?

Tags: shemos-sacred-names, speech-talking

Suppose I am having a conversation with a person who is unfamiliar with Jewish tradition, and the person casually attempts to pronounce the Shem Hameforash according to its letters, as some secular historians do. Should I utter a response of some kind, such as ברוך הוא וברוך שמו οr ברוך שם כבוד? Does it matter what the attempt sounded like?

[Related](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/20465/why-cant-we-say-gods-name) and [Related](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/23463/which-names-of-hashem-can-cant-we-say-in-regular-conversation)

Comment: this question and answer seem very relevant http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/34294/ripping-garments-when-hearing-hashems-name and this one too http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16398/boruch-shem-kevod-malchuso-lolam-voed-after-saying-hashems-name-in-error

Answer (score 2):

It depends on if the person believes in God in the way Jews do: As a single entity with no shituf (so this excludes most, but not all, Christians).

[Rambam Yesodey haTorah Chapter 6 Halacha 8](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/904982/jewish/Chapter-Six.htm)

> However, should a Jewish heretic write a Torah scroll, it and the name of God it contains must be burnt, since he does not believe in the sanctity of [God's] name and did not compose it for this purpose. Rather, he considers this to be similar to any other text. Since this is his intent, the names [of God he writes] do not become holy.
>
> In contrast, if a gentile writes [God's] name, it should be buried.

So it depends on the intent of the speaker when he said the name.

And from http://www.mesora.org/AnsweringAmen2011.html

> ... answering “Amen” to the bracha of a kofer/apikoris, an individual who denies a fundamental yesod of Judaism, such as Torah from Sinai, or possesses a distorted idea of God. As noted above, the Rambam clearly indicates one should not answer “Amen” to such a bracha, and based on the above explanation, it would seem this individual lacks the ability to create any true halachic statement as it relates to God.

You have a separate problem that the person is unlikely to have pronounced the name correctly. So it is probably not God's name anyway.

Comment: That's very helpful. I am also interested in the case where the person is not a kofer, but is simply ignorant.

Comment: This discusses writings or saying blessings. What about just hearing their saying name?

Comment: @DoubleAA Why should that be any different? The operative part of the blessing is the name after all.

Comment: @Ariel Because all you've shown is we don't say Amen in that circumstance. But in the OP's case, should he say Baruch uVaruch Shemo? Should he act as did the people and the priests who stood in the courtyard that when they heard the high priest pronounce God's name as written they would kneel, prostrate, fall on their faces and cry out Baruch Shem etc.? Perhaps in this case one should tear Kriya like the Sanhedrin does when hearing about "blessing" of God's name?

Comment: @DoubleAA "since he does not believe in the sanctity of [God's] name and did not compose it for this purpose.... Since this is his intent, the names [of God he writes] do not become holy." If the person saying it does not believe in a single God then the word he speaks has no holiness.

Comment: @Ariel You assume writing == talking; speaking is much less concerned with creating a "holy object" as writing is so they may be different. Also you haven't dealt with the case where the speaker is Unitarian or Muslim.

Comment: @DoubleAA Not me, that was R Moshe Feinstein who assumed that. And no I haven't dealt with those branches of belief - I answered what I know. There is plenty of room for more answers.

Comment: @Ariel Where did you quote RMF?

Comment: @DoubleAA Look in the source I linked to. The source for the person who I copied is RMF. (I didn't copy those words directly since they were not a direct answer, they were an explanation of the origin of the answer.)

Comment: Just two weeks ago an Orthodox Rabbi argued that "God" had become a loaded term - because no one knows what the other person is intending to convey by it.  There was a custom of some Karaites of 1000 years ago to actually pronounce the name. http://wp.me/p2MerI-lk